# I am Unable to downgrade the node-fetch version to 2.x.x from 3.x.x

Tags: node.js, npm

So basically i want to run a gatsby project in my local system . Every time i run npm run dev-ssl.
I get an error stating

Must use import to load ES Module:
......
require() of ES modules is not supported

It seems i need to downgrade the node-fetch version which is 3.2.2 in my case.

Steps to downgrade that i did

```
npm uninstall node-fetch;

npm install node-fetch@2.6.1

npm view node-fetch version
```

It still shows version 3.x.x . I also tried with -g to delete globally but getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

npm view node-fetch version will give the version information about the package in npm registry.
To view the locally installed version you can use npm ls node-fetch.